# Mysql select condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have the following table:

```
match_id player_1 player_2
1        AAA      BBB
2        CCC      DDD
3        CCC      AAA
```

I want to know match_id of match between players AAA and BBB, but i don't know their exact order (AAA vs BBB or BBB vs AAA).

For now i use construction like `WHERE (('player_1' = AAA AND 'player_2' = BBB) OR ('player_1' = BBB AND 'player_2' = AAA))`, but it can't use keys, so i doubt it is the most efficient one.

It worked well on small table (1k+ entries), but now i am working on another project where 100k+ rows in this table is possible, so i am a bit worried.

Please, suggest me best way to get match_id knowing both players.

Comment: player_1 and player_2 - they are ID's (integers)?

Comment: Iqbal's query give wrong result if player1 and player2 are same then query also retrns that row. Check my answer to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the query

```
select match_id from table_name where "AAA" in (player_1,player_2) and   
"BBB" in (player_1,player_2);
```

and don't forget to create index of the player_1 and player_2 field. it would help to improve performance

Comment: Well, this is better, although i should also check that player_1 != player_2, but in real case this won't ever happen.

Comment: player_1 IN ("AAA", "BBB" ) and player_2 IN ("AAA", "BBB" ) must be faster

Comment: @DimOK you can add the player_1!=player_2 with the given query. in this case results could be better

Answer (score 0):

Try **UNION** or **UNION ALL** to implement index on both column:

```
SELECT match_id FROM tablename 
WHERE player1='AAA' AND player2='BBB' 
UNION 
SELECT match_id FROM tablename 
WHERE player1='BBB' AND player2='AAA'
```

**OR** you can also try this

```
SELECT matchid FROM tablename 
WHERE player1 IN ('AAA', 'BBB') AND player2 IN ('AAA', 'BBB') AND 
      player1 != player2;
```

Comment: Of course i can use 2 quiries, but query using IN() looks better

Comment: Then check my other query . But i would prefer to use union in query. It is much faster than others

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using OR in condition definitely slows down your query.
I propose to change approach a bit. Please, check whether your model allows to store players in 'sorted' way (by ID if you use IDs, or alphabetically if you use names):
Every time you have two players to store, place to player_1 the one which goes alphabetically/numerically first, and in player_2 the another one.

Assuming what both *AAA vs BBB* and *BBB vs AAA* will always be stored as ('AAA', 'BBB'), you may shorten your query to:

```
WHERE ('player_1' = 'AAA' AND 'player_2' = 'BBB')
```

Comment: No, unfortunately there is too much stuff connected with players order, i cannot sort it or change in any way.